# Validaiting emails with Net.Mail MailAddress

Tags: c#, .net

I have [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/407102) on SO about validating emails with MailAddress and have produced the folowing code:

```
    try
                    {
                        var address = new MailAddress(value.Email);
                    }
                    catch (FormatException)
                    {
                        emailError = "Invalid Email";

 }
```

To my great surprise the string `ndskfndlfk@sdflsdf` validates as good email.
Any idea why is it so?

Comment: That might not be valid WWW domain name but on a private network I think it is a valid domain name.   If you want to get more selective then Regex.

Comment: Beware: do not go overboard on validating email addresses. Believe me, it's more hassle than it's worth.

Comment: In case you are going to stay with that I posted as an answer.

Comment: @Arran: Totally agree.  If the email address is coming from a user registration, I just send a typical verification email with a confirmation link to the address in question.  That way it not only validates the email address, but also verifies that it's real.

Comment: It's valid everywhere, see the relevant RFCs. Also see newgtlds which will probably shake up some bad assumptions about host names. Note that you cannot reliably validate email addresses with regular expressions; see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/201378) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to filter those email addresses, you could use the little utility found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which uses Regex to validate email addresses. Note that this is the .Net 4.0 version - it's a little different for 4.5.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class RegexUtilities
{
   bool invalid = false;

   public bool IsValidEmail(string strIn)
   {
       invalid = false;
       if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(strIn))
          return false;

       // Use IdnMapping class to convert Unicode domain names.
       strIn = Regex.Replace(strIn, @"(@)(.+)$", this.DomainMapper);
       if (invalid) 
          return false;

       // Return true if strIn is in valid e-mail format.
       return Regex.IsMatch(strIn, 
              @"^(?("")(""[^""]+?""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))" + 
              @"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,17}))$", 
              RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
   }

   private string DomainMapper(Match match)
   {
      // IdnMapping class with default property values.
      IdnMapping idn = new IdnMapping();

      string domainName = match.Groups[2].Value;
      try {
         domainName = idn.GetAscii(domainName);
      }
      catch (ArgumentException) {
         invalid = true;      
      }      
      return match.Groups[1].Value + domainName;
   }
}
```

Otherwise, if it's for user registration, I usually just depend on email verification - i.e. the system sends the user an email with a link, and clicking the link therefore validates that the email address is real.

It is possible for a *valid* email address not to be a *real* one.  In other words, it may even pass a perfect validation system, but that's no guarantee that it exists.

Answer (score 1):

That might not be valid WWW domain name but on a private network I think it is a valid domain name. If you want to get more selective then Regex.

I try and parse *legit* email (eliminate phony used by spam) using Regex and it is messy.

If you have access to the actual email header then it does not really get easier but it get more accurate.